# unable to find range of given function

Tags: functions

So I am given the function, $f(x) = \ln|\sqrt{x} - 4|$. I am to find the domain and range of this function. Now I know that the domain of this function would be $(16,\infty)$ because $\log$ is defined for $x>0$.

About range, can someone guide me what it would be? I know that it is all the possible values this can ouput, so is it $(-\infty,\infty)$? This is just a vague guess and if it is actually correct, can someone explain why?

Comment: It's correct -- ask yourself what happens to the *input* of $\ln$ as $x$ gets closer to $16$ from the right. What are the outputs you get from $\ln$ for those inputs? Then ask the same question, but as $x$ goes to positive infinity.

Comment: The absolute value bars mean that $1$ is in the domain of the function as well.  The argument of the $\ln$ is $|\sqrt 1-4|=3 \gt 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the domain is $[0,\infty)\setminus\{16\}$, since those are the numbers for which $\log\left|\sqrt x-4\right|$ makes sense.

And since the range of the logarithm function is $\Bbb R$ and every number greater than $0$ is of the form $\sqrt x-4$ for some $x>16$, the range of your function is $\Bbb R$.